# making Ajax call in wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in WP in which ,I have simple form I am making call to DB but it is not responding and no reply is received.I think there is problem here

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","info.php?q="+val,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I even tried to make call through full path of info.php but it is not working.I can run the code fine seperately.I mean outside of Wordpress.
Please suggest

Comment: Have you set the `onreadystatechange` callback?

Comment: @OlafDietsche  yes everything perfect.. and it is working fine seperately..

Comment: In wp all ajax requests must go through the admin.php.. anyhow, have you tried to read this : http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins `??